# "Jeff is not a swimmer", symbolically

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have to turn this into symbolic language:

> A: No swimmers are overweight
>   B: Jeff is overweight
>   Therefore, Jeff is not a swimmer

I got
$$A\to\neg B$$
$$B$$
$$\therefore\neg A$$
What do you think? Am I close?
Also I would say this is valid via universal modus tollens.

Comment: Try $S=\text{Swimmer}$, $W = \text{Overweight}$, $J = \text{Jeff}$.  Also, to avoid predicate logic, you may need to translate the first statement from "there does not exist a swimmer who is overweight" to "all swimmers are not overweight".

Comment: So you would write it the same but using the variables you listed? Instead of A and b?

Comment: S→¬W
J→W
∴J→¬S

?

Comment: That looks good.  The problem before was that you were using $A$ (similarly for B) to refer to both being a swimmer, and the statement "No swimmers are overweight".  You shouldn't use the same variable to refer to two different things.

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me a lot!

Comment: I think that your current solution here is fine, but out of curiosity, is there a reason you are not using Predicate Logic?  That is the most direct translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct, where $A$ means "swimmer" and $B$ means "overweight".

One thing to point out: You translated "no swimmer is overweight" as $A \to \lnot B$. That is fine, but a more direct translation might be $\lnot (A \land B)$.
I would think of "$A \to \lnot B$" as "every swimmer is not overweight", and "$\lnot (A \land B)$" as "no swimmer is overweight." But of course the statements are logically equivalent, so it doesn't matter too much. Just pick the one you think is a more direct translation.

Answer (score 0):

When the domain of discussion is implicitly *about Jeff* then, the modus tollens statement is okay.

> $$\rm S\to\neg W, W \vdash \neg S$$
>
> - If Jeff is a swimmer then Jeff is not overweight
> - Jeff is overweight
> - Therefore: Jeff is not a swimmer.

Otherwise, as suggested by @DanielV, you will need a predicate for being Jeff.

> $$\rm S\to\neg W, J\to W\, \vdash\, J\to\neg S$$
>
> - If it is a swimmer, then it is not overweight.
> - If it is Jeff, then it is overweight.
> - Therefore: If it is Jeff then it is not a swimmer.

This is equivalent to the Hypothetical Syllogism.  $\rm J\to W\,, W\to \neg S\, \vdash\, J\to\neg S$